# npm not installing npm gives a TypeError every time I run it

Tags: reactjs

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
at Object. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\agent.js:114:44)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js:5:33)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\agent.js:161:25)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or n

Comment: I reinstalled node but still showing same error also same error for installing yarn installing and creating react app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a problem with your npm installation....

Try uninstalling node along with npm, and intall it again.

just search on windows an exe called uninstall Node.js and run it..

Then, install a fresh version of stable node from [Node.js website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Comment: I tried this... it also showing node version..

Comment: same error for installing yarn installing and creating react app

Comment: Run this and then try to install: `npm install --global npm@7`